# Oauth 2.0 RestSharp passing accesstoken

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, restsharp, web-api-testing, umbraco8

Following on from my last question I have made some progress but still stuck

I am able to obtain the accessToken using this SetUp method in the test class

but when I try to run the test CanGetAllCountries it still says it is unauthorized

How can i pass the accessToken to authorize the second test?

```
public class APITestCustomer
{
    public static string baseUrl = "https://www.example.net/umbraco/api/";
    

[SetUp]
public void OAuthLogonSetup()
{

    var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("UsersApi/Logon") { Method = Method.POST };
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("Username", "xxxxxx");
    request.AddParameter("Password", "xxxxxx");
    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var responseJson = response.Content;
    var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson)["accessToken"].ToString();

    //Assert.That(token.Contains("test"));

}


        [Test]
        public void CanGetAllCountries()
        {
            
            RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("CountryApi/GetAll", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just save your token the same way you save the url, not static but a class property. Or just return the token as the result of OAuthLogonSetup() method :) also on the AddHeader you should add the token string concatenated with Bearer: $"Bearer {token}", for example.

Comment: @JesúsNarváez thanks for the reply, I think I tried that already could you please give an example? many thanks again.

Comment: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ACCESS_TOKEN); check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor?view=net-5.0

Comment: @JesúsNarváez thanks, maybe i'm having a bad day but could you show me where i would put it :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

For reaching this you could use the following modifications on your code:

```
public class APITestCustomer
{
    public static string baseUrl = "https://www.example.net/umbraco/api/";
    private string token;
    

[SetUp]
public void OAuthLogonSetup()
{

    var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("UsersApi/Logon") { Method = Method.POST };
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("Username", "xxxxxx");
    request.AddParameter("Password", "xxxxxx");
    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var responseJson = response.Content;
    token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson)["accessToken"].ToString();

    //Assert.That(token.Contains("test"));

}


        [Test]
        public void CanGetAllCountries()
        {
            
            RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("CountryApi/GetAll", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks again but i'm now getting 'rest request does not contain a definition for 'headers'

Comment: @Steven983 Then you can try this code instead :  request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

Comment: It is working now, thank you so much for your time.